# Can I use middleware to provide service injections in Azure Functions on .NET 5?

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-functions, middleware

Is it possible to use middleware in the newest Azure Functions (with .NET 5) to register a new service with DI that is scoped to the function call?

I want to use this so that I can inspect the function context and add add some tenant-specific services that can be injected to the function class's constructor.

Alternatively, could I add a service or object that is injected into the function's method as an argument.

```
// Method injection would look like this:
public Task MyFunction(FunctionContext context, ITenantSpecificService service)
{
   // service would be set in the middleware
}
```

I can manually create an object and add it to the `FunctionContext.Items`, but that's just not as clean as using the dependency injection system built-in to Functions.

Comment: Have you thought about creating a factory which can return a tenant specific implementation ? In this case, you will register all tenant specific implementations against `ITenantSpecificService` in startup and your factory method will return the needed type as needed for each request.

Comment: I have done that in the past, but would rather push the tenant-specific code down into the infrastructure as much as possible.